# Biblatex bibliography quotes break when using fontspec

Tags: xetex, fontspec, punctuation

As soon as I use `fontspec` in my biblatex xelatex document, my quotes stop appearing as proper quotes `"`, and start appearing as a pair of `` and ''.

My minimal working example, first:

```
\documentclass{book}
\listfiles
\usepackage[stretch=10]{microtype}
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{./bibliography/references.bib}


\begin{document}
Hello world [\cite{Bonaini_Memoria}]

\printbibliography
\end{document
```

Everything looks good here:
[image]

then I add `setmainfont`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\listfiles
\usepackage[stretch=10]{microtype}
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{./bibliography/references.bib}


\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
Hello world [\cite{Bonaini_Memoria}]

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and the thing breaks:

[image]

For completeness here is my bibliography biblatex entry:

```
@Article{Bonaini_Memoria,
  author="Bonaini, F.",
  title={Memoria unica sincrona di Leonardo Fibonacci novamente scoperta.},
  journaltitle="Giornale Storico degli Archivi Toscani.",
  date=1857,
  volume="Vol. I.",
  pages={239--246},
  language={italian}
```

This seems a mystery to me! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: What is weird, is if I take out the `setmainfont` directive, and instead `usepackage{libertineotf}` everything works great. :?

Answer (score 9):

Putting `\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}` should be useful for this case.

Please see [this post by Alan Munn on fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249/3235). That question and answer both by Alan is excellent for font management.

Comment: Did I put the right link?

Comment: @percusse Thanks a lot. That is it. and what a post it is.

Comment: In his answer Alan uses `[Ligatures=TeX]`. What is the advantage of using `[Mapping=tex-text]` or vise versa?

Comment: In fact `Ligatures` should be used instead, as per `fontspec` manual: `but for
consistency Ligatures=TeX will perform the same function as Mapping=tex-text.`

Comment: `[Mapping=tex-text]` I believe was an old way of indicating that `fontspec` should replicate the typical ligature behavior of Latex.  It is now the way that tells XeTeX to use these ligatures whereas `Ligatures=TeX` is for LuaTeX. Fontspec will work with `Ligature=TeX` when using XeTeX; I do not think th reverse is true.

Comment: Although this works, it feels like a workaroud and not a real solution. Is there a way to have biblatex/biber output unicode quotes, instead of TeX ligatures?

Comment: @RuudvA No this is the solution. I am afraid no other possibilities. Actually this is not a workaround.